# Getting java.net.ConnectException whenever I run my test case

Tags: java, json, api, testng, rest-assured-jsonpath

```
package restAssuredTesting;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DemoProjectForGet {

    @Test
    public void getWhetherDetails() {
        given()
        .when()
        .get("http:/restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city/Mumbai")
        .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .statusLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK")
        .assertThat().body("City", equalTo("Mumbai"))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a slash in http://.

```
.get("http:/restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city/Mumbai")
```

It should be:

```
.get("http://restapi.demoqa.com/utilities/weather/city/Mumbai")
```

Comment: Ohh yes it is working fine now. Thank you so much, sir.

Comment: Happy to hear it :).  You can click the check mark to close out the question.